# Using a computer headset connected to a voice amplifier?

Tags: stereo, mono

I'm trying to plug a stereo 3.5 mm headset microphone jack to a voice amplifier.

So, besides being able to connect it directly to the PC, I'd like to be able to connect it first to an amplifier to add gain, and then plug it into the line-in of the PC from the line-out of the amplifier...

But I'm not able to do it for some reason.

Adapters won't work, and I even had a technician solder it to a mono plug, but I get strong digital noise and very low and distorted voice sound.

Is there a work-around for this? Or do headsets with mono mic jack even exist?

Comment: Ignoring all the "what you did" stuff, what actually are you trying to achieve dude?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a pre-amp.  A pre-amp is what takes a mic level signal up to line level.  An amp is what goes from line level to the level necessary to drive speakers.  The amp expects a line level input that it would boost up to speaker level.  The Line output on an amp is generally just a pass through or a duplication of the same signal as came in without any amplification.

If it is a pass through then it would have no impact.  If it is duplicating it, then the ultra low signal level of a mic level vs a line level would end up adding a lot of noise due to colliding with the noise floor of the hardware duplicating the signal.